# How to get fields by name in query Python?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I use Mysql Connection in Python script.

How can I get results from table by names?

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM local")
```

Now I do this by index:

```
results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
   print row[0] //
```

Instead that I wanna get fields by names like as: print `row["name"]`

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195139/how-to-retrieve-sql-result-column-value-using-column-name-in-python

Comment: I did not found solution there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead you can use pandas library

```
import pandas as pd
sql = "SELECT * FROM local"
df = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['name'])
```

I hope this helps

Comment: How to install `pandas` in Cent OS?

Comment: pip install pandas

Answer (score 11):

If you are using **mysql-connector**, Try this

```
cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM myTable")
results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
    print( row )
```

If dictionary is True, the cursor returns rows as dictionaries.

Comment: You Sir deserve a medal. 2 hours of research on Internet, no solutions works except yours ! Fast, small, clean. Thanks so much. I upvoted you obviously.

Comment: I second the medal: Hero Pythonista First Class.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the MySQLdb for python you can transmit to your cursor instance a DictCursor.

Here is a full example using MySQLdb:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="test",passwd="test",db="test")
>>> cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test_user")
2
>>> results = cursor.fetchall()
>>> for result in results:
...    print(result["username"])
test1
test2
```

Hope it's useful.

Also, you can find answers here suitable for your tuple situation.
[python mysql.connector DictCursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769873/python-mysql-connector-dictcursor)

Comment: It does not work "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: What module for mysql are you using ?

Comment: `import mysql.connector`

Comment: For mysql connector, use the answer from @Anoop