# Getting error while using MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor in MYSQL_CURSORCLASS

Tags: python, mysql-python

In my Flask application, in order to get results in dictionary format in MySQLdb, I added the statement:

```
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor
```

I got the error

```
kwargs['cursorclass'] = getattr(MySQLdb.cursors, current_app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'])
```

TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string

My application was running perfectly fine before adding this statement. After some searching, I found out that the error seems to be caused by the given line

```
db = mysql.connection.cursor()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says, that setting needs to be a string which is then used to look up the cursor class in `MySQLdb.cursors`.

```
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = "DictCursor"
```